# merging 2 array of objects of different length based on same property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

I want to merge 2 array of objects based on **"foodtypeid"of arr1 == "id of arr2**
and output a final array with all keyvalue pairs from arr1 and foodCategoryDescription,description,fullname from arr2 present  (arr1 may not be of equal length and order as arr2)

arr1 = [
{
"age": 37,
"gender": "Woman",
"holdSeatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d72",
"id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5325",
"PAXName": "Kangrou Fu",
"seatName": "10A",
"seatType": "BC",
"vip": false,
"containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63",
"foodTypeId": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a",
"locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b66",
"orderType": "Pre_Ordered",
"qty": 1,
"seatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d72"
},
{
"age": 40,
"gender": "Woman",
"holdSeatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fd4",
"id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5327",
"PAXName": "Huishao Wu",
"seatName": "21A",
"seatType": "EC",
"vip": false,
"containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63",
"foodTypeId": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d",
"locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b71",
"orderType": "Special_Meal",
"qty": 1,
"seatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fd4"
},

]

`arr2=
[
{
"categoryId": "629481212eebc502d0e6582a",
"cost": 1,
"description": "42116455",
"foodCategoryDescription": "Drink",
"foodCategoryName": "Drink",
"foodTypeMaterialIds": [
"63295a9f4a66be483cd771ab"
],
"fullName": "drink1",
"id": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a",
"partNumber": "42116455",
"placeOfProduction": "HAM",
"seatType": "EC",
"serialNumber": "42116455",
"shortName": "42116455",
"weight": 500
},
{
"categoryId": "629481212eebc502d0e6582a",
"cost": 1,
"description": "5000112547689",
"foodCategoryDescription": "Drink",
"foodCategoryName": "Drink",
"foodTypeMaterialIds": [
"63295ae54a66be483cd771ae"
],
"fullName": "drink2",
"id": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d",
"partNumber": "5000112547689",
"placeOfProduction": "HAM",
"seatType": "EC",
"serialNumber": "5000112547689",
"shortName": "5000112547689",
"weight": 500
},

]

tried this but final output ignore key value pairs from arr2

```
arr6.forEach(obj1 => {
  let obj2 = arr7.find(obj2 => obj2.id === obj1.foodTypeId);
  if (obj2) {
    let mergedObj = {...obj1, ...obj2};
    mergedArr.push(mergedObj);
  } else {
    mergedArr.push(obj1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is map each item in `arr1` to the corresponding object where:

```
arr1[x].id === arr2[y].foodTypeId
```

Also, you should probably give your object array variables better names to represent the collection. It lets the reader know what type of objects are stored in the array.

```js
const main = () => {
  const mapped = customers.map(customer => ({
    ...customer,
    ...foodTypes.find(({ id }) => id === customer.foodTypeId)
  }));
  console.log(mapped);
};

const
  customers = [{
      "age": 37,
      "gender": "Woman",
      "holdSeatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d72",
      "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5325",
      "PAXName": "Kangrou Fu",
      "seatName": "10A",
      "seatType": "BC",
      "vip": false,
      "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63",
      "foodTypeId": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a",
      "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b66",
      "orderType": "Pre_Ordered",
      "qty": 1,
      "seatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d72"
    }, {
      "age": 40,
      "gender": "Woman",
      "holdSeatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fd4",
      "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5327",
      "PAXName": "Huishao Wu",
      "seatName": "21A",
      "seatType": "EC",
      "vip": false,
      "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63",
      "foodTypeId": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d",
      "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b71",
      "orderType": "Special_Meal",
      "qty": 1,
      "seatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fd4"
    },
  ],
  foodTypes = [{
    "categoryId": "629481212eebc502d0e6582a",
    "cost": 1,
    "description": "42116455",
    "foodCategoryDescription": "Drink",
    "foodCategoryName": "Drink",
    "foodTypeMaterialIds": ["63295a9f4a66be483cd771ab"],
    "fullName": "drink1",
    "id": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a",
    "partNumber": "42116455",
    "placeOfProduction": "HAM",
    "seatType": "EC",
    "serialNumber": "42116455",
    "shortName": "42116455",
    "weight": 500
  }, {
    "categoryId": "629481212eebc502d0e6582a",
    "cost": 1,
    "description": "5000112547689",
    "foodCategoryDescription": "Drink",
    "foodCategoryName": "Drink",
    "foodTypeMaterialIds": ["63295ae54a66be483cd771ae"],
    "fullName": "drink2",
    "id": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d",
    "partNumber": "5000112547689",
    "placeOfProduction": "HAM",
    "seatType": "EC",
    "serialNumber": "5000112547689",
    "shortName": "5000112547689",
    "weight": 500
  },
];
  
main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Instead of just spreading the values into a flat object, you could created a nested object. This way the `foodType` info is contained. You could also do this with `location`.

```js
const main = () => {
  const mapped = customers.map(({ foodTypeId, ...customer }) => ({
    ...customer,
    foodType: foodTypes.find(({ id }) => id === foodTypeId)
  }));
  console.log(mapped);
};

const
  customers = [{
      "age": 37,
      "gender": "Woman",
      "holdSeatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d72",
      "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5325",
      "PAXName": "Kangrou Fu",
      "seatName": "10A",
      "seatType": "BC",
      "vip": false,
      "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63",
      "foodTypeId": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a",
      "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b66",
      "orderType": "Pre_Ordered",
      "qty": 1,
      "seatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d72"
    }, {
      "age": 40,
      "gender": "Woman",
      "holdSeatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fd4",
      "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5327",
      "PAXName": "Huishao Wu",
      "seatName": "21A",
      "seatType": "EC",
      "vip": false,
      "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63",
      "foodTypeId": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d",
      "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b71",
      "orderType": "Special_Meal",
      "qty": 1,
      "seatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fd4"
    },
  ],
  foodTypes = [{
    "categoryId": "629481212eebc502d0e6582a",
    "cost": 1,
    "description": "42116455",
    "foodCategoryDescription": "Drink",
    "foodCategoryName": "Drink",
    "foodTypeMaterialIds": ["63295a9f4a66be483cd771ab"],
    "fullName": "drink1",
    "id": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a",
    "partNumber": "42116455",
    "placeOfProduction": "HAM",
    "seatType": "EC",
    "serialNumber": "42116455",
    "shortName": "42116455",
    "weight": 500
  }, {
    "categoryId": "629481212eebc502d0e6582a",
    "cost": 1,
    "description": "5000112547689",
    "foodCategoryDescription": "Drink",
    "foodCategoryName": "Drink",
    "foodTypeMaterialIds": ["63295ae54a66be483cd771ae"],
    "fullName": "drink2",
    "id": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d",
    "partNumber": "5000112547689",
    "placeOfProduction": "HAM",
    "seatType": "EC",
    "serialNumber": "5000112547689",
    "shortName": "5000112547689",
    "weight": 500
  },
];
  
main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```